# Change root directory by using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My project folder structure is

```
- /var/www/project/
--- application
--- cache
--- library
--- public
```

The current root dir in apache conf is

```
/var/www/project/public
```

Now I have two different interfaces.

New interface structure

```
- ./public/new/build/
--- index.html
--- css/
--- images/
```

Old interface structure

```
- ./public/
--- index.php
--- css
--- images
--- js
--- some_php_files_used_by_index.php
```

Index.php is the part of Zend-Framework project.

I can't edit apache's config, and I have to edit my .htaccess file to be able:

http://example.com/ - show new interface from public/new/build with its resources;

http://example.com/old/ - show old interface from /public/ with its own resources

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can have these 2 rules in site root i.e. `/var/www/project/public/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# old site
RewriteRule ^old(/.*)?$ /$1 [L,NC]

# new site
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+old[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!new/build/).*$ new/build/$1 [L,NC]
```